# how to add a sidebar to a woocommerce page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a wordpress site and I'm using the woocommerce pluging. I have a product page and the sidebar is showing at the bottom of the page. How do I edit the code to put the sidebar so it shows the sidebar on the left of the main content area. NOT under the main content area?

The code for the template is:

```
    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_before_main_content hook
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper - 10 (outputs opening divs for the content)
         * @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 20
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );
    ?>

        <?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', true ) ) : ?>

            <h1 class="page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' ); ?>

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php
                /**
                 * woocommerce_before_shop_loop hook
                 *
                 * @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20
                 * @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
                 */
                do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );
            ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

                <?php woocommerce_product_subcategories(); ?>

                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                    <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

                <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

            <?php
                /**
                 * woocommerce_after_shop_loop hook
                 *
                 * @hooked woocommerce_pagination - 10
                 */
                do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' );
            ?>

        <?php elseif ( ! woocommerce_product_subcategories( array( 'before' => woocommerce_product_loop_start( false ), 'after' => woocommerce_product_loop_end( false ) ) ) ) : ?>

            <?php wc_get_template( 'loop/no-products-found.php' ); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_after_main_content hook
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end - 10 (outputs closing divs for the content)
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content' );
    ?>

    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_sidebar hook
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );
    ?>
```

Comment: Can we see it live ? I think it needs `CSS` changes rather than woocommerce file. But still can't say anything perfectly.

Comment: this is the url for the page: http://goldenhersh.co.il/en/shop/  I would like the 'contact us' to display in the sidebar. It i currently under the products at the end of the page.

Comment: you want it in all product category pages or only in shop category page ?

Comment: (what is the difference between product and shop - product, one product, shop all of them?) I want the sidebar on every page on the site, shop and single product eg also on http://goldenhersh.co.il/en/product/aloe-vera-soothing-face-cream/

Comment: Okay .. So you need to modify template file and CSS also .. But for that I need to look into your template. But here is the quick and **ugly** fix for this :
add `#main{width:80% !important; float:left;}` in your `style.css`

Answer (score 6):

You will need to edit the wrapper to support the WooCommerce template system. This is done in one of two ways.

The first would be to create a `woocommerce.php` file (using your theme's sidebar layout template as a base) in the theme directory proper. This will override the WooCommerce wrapper system and `archive-product.php` template. It will give you a bit more control since it will work based on your theme. You will need to replace the loop in the template with `<?php woocommerce_content(); ?>` You can comment out the sidebar in your example above and use the theme's set sidebar location with your woocommerce sidebar `<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );?>`. See http://docs.woothemes.com/document/third-party-custom-theme-compatibility/ for more information on this.

The other option would be to edit the WooCommerce wrapper to adjust the classes so your sidebar would have enough room. The `<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content' );?>` is the end of the wrapper. That's in the WooCommerce template system under `global > wrapper-start.php` and `global > wrapper-end.php` (make sure these are copied over to your theme directory under your woocommerce folder in their respective folders).

Comment: I have been looking for this for so long, three cheers for the author of the above answer

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar', 'mahi_woocommerce_sidebar_action' );

function mahi_woocommerce_sidebar_action(){

    echo "add Content here";
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).