# woocommerce move sidebar from bottom of the page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30568253/how-to-add-a-sidebar-to-a-woocommerce-page) that is similar to my issue. I have a particular wrapper that I have placed around the woocommerce content, but the sidebar still appear at the bottom of the page. Is there any solution? I have hooked the `woocommerce_before_main_content` and `woocommerce_after_main_content` butt the sidebar still remain on the bottom and I'm not able to find any sidebar file or documentation to style it.

```
function udini_woocommerce_before_main_content()
  {
    ?>
      <div class="container-fluid content-wrapper" id="udini-woocommece-wrapper">
    <?php
  }
  add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'udini_woocommerce_before_main_content', 10 );

  function udini_woocommerce_after_main_content()
  {
    ?>
      </div>
    <?php
  }
  add_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'udini_woocommerce_after_main_content', 10 );

remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper', 10);
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end', 10);
```

Comment: what theme are you using?

Comment: @c0c0b33f it's a custom theme I wrote